# Isolating an instruction in one page

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb

I have written main function with one assembly add instruction. According to the GDB, the code is

```
(gdb) disass /r main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004ed <+0>: 55  push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004ee <+1>: 48 89 e5    mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004f1 <+4>: 01 c1   add    %eax,%ecx
   0x00000000004004f3 <+6>: 5d  pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004004f4 <+7>: c3  retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

As I looked the IP and print the memory content after that, I see

```
(gdb) x/10x $rip
0x4004f1 <main+4>:  0xc35dc101  0x1f0f2e66  0x00000084  0x41900000
0x400501 <__libc_csu_init+1>:   0xff894157  0x89495641  0x495541f6  0x5441d589
0x400511 <__libc_csu_init+17>:  0xf8258d4c  0x55002008
```

Actually, I want to put my `add %eax, %ecx` in just one page and isolate it from before and after that. Here, I don't have the information about pages and don't know if `add` and `retq` are in the same page or not.

Any comment?

P.S: As you can see `c3` in `0xc35dc101` is the `retq` instruction. The question is, what are the subsequent bytes?

Comment: x86/x86-64 is little endian so the 32-bit value `0xc35dc101` as bytes is in reverse order. which is 0x01, 0xc1, 0x5f, 0xc3. They aren't the bytes after the instruction - they are before. Retq is a single byte instruction 0xc3.

Comment: Use `x/10bx` to dump bytes instead of doublewords.

Comment: There has to be some instructions after `add %eax, %ecx` because that instruction cannot by itself terminate the program. So there will be either an invalid instruction after it or perhaps you want to fill the rest of the (4KB?) page with NOPs, so that your program doesn't crash. But with this way, technically speaking, NOPs are instructions and so `add %eax, %ecx` wouldn't be alone in a single page.

Comment: I was thinking to isolate an instruction in a page in order to raise invalid opcode exception if the written assembly bytes are indeed invalid opcodes.

Comment: Why not use inline assembly (the `.byte` directive) to insert a sequence of bytes that represent an invalid instruction immediately after `add %eax, %ecx`? I think what comes after it is not important. If you want to make sure that both instructions are in the same 4KB page, then align the function that contains them on a 4KB boundary.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to isolate, you get the invalid opcode exception even if not isolated.

Comment: Since I have to rewrite the question, I posted a new one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935238 appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Sounds like you want `.balign 4096` before/after your instruction.  That will pad with NOPs to a page boundary.  This is probably not actually useful; I think you've gone down an X-Y problem rabbit hole here, especially based on your other questions.