# Generating and catching invalid instruction

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I want to isolate a custom opcode in my program in order to catch invalid opcode exception if there is any. If I write an empty main, I see an assembly sequence as below:

```
(gdb) list
1   void main()
2   {
3   }
(gdb) disass /r main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004ed <+0>: 55  push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004ee <+1>: 48 89 e5    mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004f1 <+4>: 5d  pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004004f2 <+5>: c3  retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

If I write a single random byte such as  `__asm__(".byte 0x01");` I see that it automatically append 5d and c3 to that because it assumes the opcode is ADD and so it needs more than one byte.

```
0x00000000004004f1 <+4>:    01 5d c3    add    %ebx,-0x3d(%rbp)
```

End of assembler dump.

If I put some NOP (0x90) before and after that, it doesn't also help and it will automatically append some 0x90 to 0x01.

```
0x00000000004004f1 <+4>:    90  nop
0x00000000004004f2 <+5>:    90  nop
0x00000000004004f3 <+6>:    90  nop
0x00000000004004f4 <+7>:    01 90 90 90 90 90   add    %edx,-0x6f6f6f70(%rax)
0x00000000004004fa <+13>:   90  nop
0x00000000004004fb <+14>:   5d  pop    %rbp
0x00000000004004fc <+15>:   c3  retq
```

By executing that ADD, I get segmentation fault error. Therefore, I can not distinguish seg fault and invalid instruction/opcode. I want to isolate that opcode. What about aligning with different pages and handling page faults?

Any comment?

Comment: That won't do what you want. What you have written happens to be a valid instruction. It's not invalid. Isolating on page boundary will give you a page fault instead, if the necessary further instruction bytes can't be fetched.

Comment: Okay so putting the instruction at the end of a page and giving it more and more bytes until you do not get page fault could allow you to determine the instruction length if that's what you are after. See also [Breaking the x86 ISA](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Domas-Breaking-The-x86-Instruction-Set-wp.pdf)

Comment: I have read that. Things aren't so simple though. For example, he says, use 15 bytes to zeros as an instruction and execute it and observer the length. If you put 15 bytes of zeros, you will have 7 add instructions since 0000 is a two byte add instruction. So, you can not directly run that 15 bytes to see what happens. I myself rely on gdb output to see how it translates the machine code using "disass /r".

Comment: That means I have to put 15 bytes of zero, compile the code, observer how gdb interpret that.

Comment: You don't care about gdb interpreting anything, gdb is just using a disassembler. You care about the cpu executing it. The paper I linked shows how to do that programmatically. Note you first use 1 byte, then 2, then 3, and so on up to 15. You detect the first time you don't get a page fault (for the boundary). I assume you are hunting for undocumented instructions as otherwise all you need is a disassembler.

Comment: Note that nobody appends anything to your `01` byte.  You see that `5d c3` is just the `pop %rbp; retq` sequence the compiler emits to return from the function.  What gdb does is interpret the instruction stream into full instructions.  And yes, since instruction `01` comes with a modr/m byte, gdb is going to think the next few bytes is this modr/m byte and associated SIB/displacement bytes.  Nobody added anything to your code.

Comment: You mean that cpu will only fetch `01` byte and not `01 5d c3` bytes? I think CPU also interpret `01` as an opcode that need additional bytes and will fetch them. So, the seg fault I receive is due to the absence of pop and retq and not the invalid 01 code.

Comment: @jester: I see that this topic is recognized for undocumented instructions. Actually, I want to investigate fault tolerancy by limiting the number of valid instructions. Seems that the way to find that is similar to the other people's intent.

Comment: @mahmood: No, that's *not* what \@fuz said.  He said that neither the compiler nor assembler added any bytes that you didn't ask for.  The `5d c3` were *already there*, and the `01` opcode byte consumes them as part of a longer instruction when decoded by a disassembler or by the CPU.  This isn't "adding" new bytes to the machine-code bytestream, it's "consuming" existing bytes.